# When did browsers start caching .htaccess files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

When did browsers start caching `.htaccess` files?  Everything I read says they don't.  I've tested this in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Edge and modern browsers absolutely do cache `.htaccess` files.

These are the 4 lines of code I'm using for testing purposes.  Those 4 lines are the entire `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/dogs.txt [NC]
    RewriteRule .* https://www.fakeurl.com/test/note.txt [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I comment each line with a `#`, upload and refresh my browser it continues to redirect as if nothing changed.  Minutes later still no change.  However after I clear my cache and refresh the url I get the 404 error as expected.  This works the same in every browser I tested. Am I doing something wrong?

**Update**

I added the line `RewriteEngine On` at the beginning of the file but that didn't change anything.

Comment: browsers don't cache htaccess file they cache permanent redirects which is what you're doing there. If instead of 301 you use 302, on a clean browser you will notice it will not be cache, there is a huge difference purpose from 301 and 302. You need to clear your browser history and restart it, but even so in some cases it may take awhile for it to understand it so using a different browser you haven't to access that site will give u a clear view of it.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying that!  I'm learning from the book htaccess Made Easy and sure enough the first example I use for testing screws me up for some unexpected reason.

Comment: [**For testing purposes you should always use 302 until you have the redirect working as expected, then you change it to 301.** And you should also learn more on what each code represents to understand it better, there are some other interesting code that serve other purposes, like maintenance and such...](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: As a pedantic note: a browser never loads .htaccess unless you point it there and the server allows it. It's a server configuration file. Therefore the browser cannot cache what it never even accesses. The answers have already explained what is happening, but just to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not cacheing the .httacess at all... it IS caching the 301 redirect (assuming a permament redirect)

Switch it to 302 ie [R=302,L] and try again

Comment: That worked like a champ.  One tiny question on mechanics. In the segment `[R=302,L]` the `L` tells `.htaccess` to stop rewriting.  Why would it need that?  In HTML/CSS/JS I never tell the engine to stop writing.  When the code stops it's done.  What is different about Apache that it needs to be told to stop?

Comment: You can have other rewrites below that one, that just says you are done "rewriting" just send this page now.Think of it more like a Switch/case-break block the L is the break https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp